# How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Since `printf` is not reentrant, it's not supposed to be safe to use it in a signal handler. But I've seen lots of example codes that uses `printf` this way.

So my question is: when do we need to avoid using `printf` in a signal handler, and is there a recommended replacement?

Comment: A simple and not very useful answer to the question in your title: See that `printf` call in that signal hander? Delete it.

Comment: Hello Yu Hao!  I think you will find link very interesting to read. ["Use reentrant functions for safer signal handling"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent/index.html#N101CA) I have read it after so long time, I would like to share the artificial here with you. Hope you enjoy.

Comment: Also see [Print int from signal handler using write or async-safe functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14573000/608639).

Comment: As the nice article posted above is gone - get the 2021 capture of this still very relevant and good 2005 article from https://web.archive.org/web/20210121185226/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent/index.html (of course, we all store the errno directly after the function which set it...)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use some flag variable, set that flag inside signal handler, and based on that flag call `printf()` function in main() or other part of program during normal operation.

> It is not safe to call all functions, such as `printf`, from within a signal handler. 
>      A useful technique is to use a signal handler to set a `flag` and then check that `flag`
>      from the main program and print a message if required.

Notice in example below, signal handler ding() set a flag `alarm_fired` to 1 as SIGALRM caught and in main function `alarm_fired` value is examined to conditionally call printf correctly.

```
static int alarm_fired = 0;
void ding(int sig) // can be called asynchronously
{
  alarm_fired = 1; // set flag
}
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    printf("alarm application starting\n");
    pid = fork();
    switch(pid) {
        case -1:
            /* Failure */
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            /* child */
            sleep(5);
            kill(getppid(), SIGALRM);
            exit(0);
    }
    /* if we get here we are the parent process */
    printf("waiting for alarm to go off\n");
    (void) signal(SIGALRM, ding);
    pause();
    if (alarm_fired)  // check flag to call printf
      printf("Ding!\n");
    printf("done\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

<sub>Reference: [Beginning Linux Programming, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147628), In this book exactly your code is explained (what you want), Chapter 11: Processes and Signals, page 484</sub>

Additionally, you need to take special care in writing handler functions because they can be called asynchronously. That is, a handler might be called at any point in the program, unpredictably. If two signals arrive during a very short interval, one handler can run within another. And It is considered better practice to declare `volatile sigatomic_t`, this type are always accessed atomically, avoid uncertainty about interrupting access to a variable. (read: [Atomic Data Access and Signal Handling](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC358) for detail expiation).

Read [Defining Signal Handlers](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC351) :to learn how to write a signal handler function that can be established with the `signal()` or `sigaction()` functions.
List of authorized functions in [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), calling this function inside signal handler is safe.

Comment: It is considered better practice to declare `volatile sigatomic_t alarm_fired;`

Comment: Adding a link ["What happens during this signal handling program?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712525/1673391)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: if we are working in a code of product , then we can not call pause function , flow can be anywhere when signal occur , so in that case we really dont know where to keep "if (alarm_fired)  printf("Ding!\n");" in code.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha yes, your are correct, it is suffering from race condition

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, There are two things which i could not understand.                    1. How do you know when to check the flag? So will there be multiple check points in the code at almost every point to print.                                                           2.There will definitely be race conditions where in the signal might be called before the signal registration or the signal may occur after the check point.               I think this will only help the print in some conditions but does not completely solve the problem.

Comment: @Darshanb (1) Yes, you are correct, signals are asynchronous they can happen any time in your system. But understand the signal-handlers are also called asynchronously when the signal trigger to your process you are not supposed to call signal handlers explicitly,- Secondly, there is a list of authorized functions those can be called from a signal handler. ...for unauthorized function, you have to check the `alarm_fired`  [repeadtly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766999/1673391) ...it largely depends on need and design of your application

Comment: @Darshanb (2) yes, to prevent from race conditions we declrated atomic flag

Answer (score 73):

The primary problem is that if the signal interrupts `malloc()` or some similar function, the internal state may be temporarily inconsistent while it is moving blocks of memory between the free and used list, or other similar operations.  If the code in the signal handler calls a function that then invokes `malloc()`, this may completely wreck the memory management.

The C standard takes a very conservative view of what you can do in a signal handler:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.14.1.1 The `signal` function
>
> ¶5 If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the
>   behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread
>   storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an
>   object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or the signal handler calls any function
>   in the standard library other than the `abort` function, the `_Exit` function, the
>   `quick_exit` function, or the `signal` function with the first argument equal to the
>   signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler.
>   Furthermore, if such a call to the `signal` function results in a `SIG_ERR` return, the
>   value of `errno` is indeterminate.<sup>252)</sup>
>
> <sup>252)</sup> If any signal is generated by an asynchronous signal handler, the behavior is undefined.

POSIX is a lot more generous about what you can do in a signal handler.

[Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) in the POSIX 2008 edition says:

> If the process is multi-threaded, or if the process is single-threaded and a signal handler is executed other than as the result of:
>
> - The process calling `abort()`, `raise()`, `kill()`, `pthread_kill()`, or `sigqueue()` to generate a signal that is not blocked
> - A pending signal being unblocked and being delivered before the call that unblocked it returns
>
> the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than `errno` with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the functions listed in the following table.
>
> The following table defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can invoke them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions:
>
> ```
> _Exit()             fexecve()           posix_trace_event() sigprocmask()
> _exit()             fork()              pselect()           sigqueue()
> …
> fcntl()             pipe()              sigpause()          write()
> fdatasync()         poll()              sigpending()
> ```
>
> All functions not in the above table are considered to be unsafe with respect to signals. In the presence of signals, all functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall behave as defined when called from or interrupted by a signal-catching function, with a single exception: when a signal interrupts an unsafe function and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Operations which obtain the value of `errno` and operations which assign a value to `errno` shall be async-signal-safe.
>
> When a signal is delivered to a thread, if the action of that signal specifies termination, stop, or continue, the entire process shall be terminated, stopped, or continued, respectively.

However, the `printf()` family of functions is notably absent from that list and may not be called safely from a signal handler.

The **POSIX 2016** update extends the list of safe functions to include, in particular, a large number of the functions from `<string.h>`, which is a particularly valuable addition (or was a particularly frustrating oversight).  The list is now:

```
_Exit()              getppid()            sendmsg()            tcgetpgrp()
_exit()              getsockname()        sendto()             tcsendbreak()
abort()              getsockopt()         setgid()             tcsetattr()
accept()             getuid()             setpgid()            tcsetpgrp()
access()             htonl()              setsid()             time()
aio_error()          htons()              setsockopt()         timer_getoverrun()
aio_return()         kill()               setuid()             timer_gettime()
aio_suspend()        link()               shutdown()           timer_settime()
alarm()              linkat()             sigaction()          times()
bind()               listen()             sigaddset()          umask()
cfgetispeed()        longjmp()            sigdelset()          uname()
cfgetospeed()        lseek()              sigemptyset()        unlink()
cfsetispeed()        lstat()              sigfillset()         unlinkat()
cfsetospeed()        memccpy()            sigismember()        utime()
chdir()              memchr()             siglongjmp()         utimensat()
chmod()              memcmp()             signal()             utimes()
chown()              memcpy()             sigpause()           wait()
clock_gettime()      memmove()            sigpending()         waitpid()
close()              memset()             sigprocmask()        wcpcpy()
connect()            mkdir()              sigqueue()           wcpncpy()
creat()              mkdirat()            sigset()             wcscat()
dup()                mkfifo()             sigsuspend()         wcschr()
dup2()               mkfifoat()           sleep()              wcscmp()
execl()              mknod()              sockatmark()         wcscpy()
execle()             mknodat()            socket()             wcscspn()
execv()              ntohl()              socketpair()         wcslen()
execve()             ntohs()              stat()               wcsncat()
faccessat()          open()               stpcpy()             wcsncmp()
fchdir()             openat()             stpncpy()            wcsncpy()
fchmod()             pause()              strcat()             wcsnlen()
fchmodat()           pipe()               strchr()             wcspbrk()
fchown()             poll()               strcmp()             wcsrchr()
fchownat()           posix_trace_event()  strcpy()             wcsspn()
fcntl()              pselect()            strcspn()            wcsstr()
fdatasync()          pthread_kill()       strlen()             wcstok()
fexecve()            pthread_self()       strncat()            wmemchr()
ffs()                pthread_sigmask()    strncmp()            wmemcmp()
fork()               raise()              strncpy()            wmemcpy()
fstat()              read()               strnlen()            wmemmove()
fstatat()            readlink()           strpbrk()            wmemset()
fsync()              readlinkat()         strrchr()            write()
ftruncate()          recv()               strspn()
futimens()           recvfrom()           strstr()
getegid()            recvmsg()            strtok_r()
geteuid()            rename()             symlink()
getgid()             renameat()           symlinkat()
getgroups()          rmdir()              tcdrain()
getpeername()        select()             tcflow()
getpgrp()            sem_post()           tcflush()
getpid()             send()               tcgetattr()
```

As a result, you either end up using `write()` without the formatting support provided by `printf()` et al, or you end up setting a flag that you test (periodically) in appropriate places in your code.  This technique is ably demonstrated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891065/15168) by [Grijesh Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1673391/grijesh-chauhan).

---

#### Standard C functions and signal safety

[chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891799?noredirect=1#comment69360388_16891799) an interesting question, to which I have no more than a partial answer:

> How come most string functions from `<string.h>` or the character class functions from `<ctype.h>` and many more C standard library functions are not in the list above? An implementation would need to be purposely evil to make `strlen()` unsafe to call from a signal handler.

For many of the functions in `<string.h>`, it is hard to see why they were not declared async-signal safe, and I'd agree the `strlen()` is a prime example, along with `strchr()`, `strstr()`, etc.  On the other hand, other functions such as `strtok()`, `strcoll()` and `strxfrm()` are rather complex and are not likely to be async-signal safe.  Because `strtok()` retains state between calls, and the signal handler could not easily tell whether some part of the code that is using `strtok()` would be messed up.  The `strcoll()` and `strxfrm()` functions work with locale-sensitive data, and loading the locale involves all sorts of state setting.

The functions (macros) from `<ctype.h>` are all locale-sensitive, and therefore could run into the same issues as `strcoll()` and `strxfrm()`.

I find it hard to see why the mathematical functions from `<math.h>` are not async-signal safe, unless it is because they could be affected by a SIGFPE (floating point exception), though about the only time I see one of those these days is for *integer* division by zero.  Similar uncertainty arises from `<complex.h>`, `<fenv.h>` and `<tgmath.h>`.

Some of the functions in `<stdlib.h>` could be exempted — `abs()` for example.  Others are specifically problematic: `malloc()` and family are prime examples.

A similar assessment could be made for the other headers in Standard C (2011) used in a POSIX environment. (Standard C is so restrictive there's no interest in analyzing them in a pure Standard C environment.)  Those marked 'locale-dependent' are unsafe because manipulating locales might require memory allocation, etc.

- `<assert.h>` — *Probably not safe*
- `<complex.h>` — *Possibly safe*
- `<ctype.h>` — Not safe
- `<errno.h>` — Safe
- `<fenv.h>` — *Probably not safe*
- `<float.h>` — No functions
- `<inttypes.h>` — Locale-sensitive functions (unsafe)
- `<iso646.h>` — No functions
- `<limits.h>` — No functions
- `<locale.h>` — Locale-sensitive functions (unsafe)
- `<math.h>` — *Possibly safe*
- `<setjmp.h>` — Not safe
- `<signal.h>` — Allowed
- `<stdalign.h>` — No functions
- `<stdarg.h>` — No functions
- `<stdatomic.h>` — *Possibly safe, probably not safe*
- `<stdbool.h>` — No functions
- `<stddef.h>` — No functions
- `<stdint.h>` — No functions
- `<stdio.h>` — Not safe
- `<stdlib.h>` — Not all safe (some are allowed; others are not)
- `<stdnoreturn.h>` — No functions
- `<string.h>` — Not all safe
- `<tgmath.h>` — *Possibly safe*
- `<threads.h>` — *Probably not safe*
- `<time.h>` — Locale-dependent (but `time()` is explicitly allowed)
- `<uchar.h>` — Locale-dependent
- `<wchar.h>` — Locale-dependent
- `<wctype.h>` — Locale-dependent

Analyzing the POSIX headers would be … harder in that there are a lot of them, and some functions might be safe but many won't be … but also simpler because POSIX says which functions are async-signal safe (not many of them).  Note that a header like `<pthread.h>` has three safe functions and many unsafe functions.

***NB:** Almost all of the assessment of C functions and headers in a POSIX environment is semi-educated guesswork.  It is no sense a definitive statement from a standards body.*

Comment: How come most string functions from `<string.h>` or the character class functions from `<ctype.h>` and many more C standard library functions are not in the list above? An implementation would need to be purposely evil to make `strlen()` unsafe to call from a signal handler.

Comment: @chqrlie: interesting question — see the update (there was no way to fit that much into comments sensibly).

Comment: Thank you for your in depth analysis. Regarding the `<ctype.h>` stuff, it is locale specific and could cause problems if the signal interrupts a locale setting function, but once the locale is loaded, using them should be safe. I guess, in some complex situations, loading the locale data could be done incrementally, thus making the functions from `<ctype.h>` unsafe. The conclusion remains: *When in doubt, abstain.*

Comment: @chqrlie: I agree that the moral of the story should be _When in doubt, abstain_.  That's a nice summary.

Comment: What about trapping signals from a shell such as bash? is this the same as using signal handlers? Because with `trap` it's usually to define code, e.g. `printf`, `rm`, `mkdir`, etc. I've not seen anything about using shell code when `trapping` signals so I suppose is safe

Comment: If you're asking about whether to worry about what you do in the action for  `trap` and catching signals in a shell script, the answer is "you don't have to worry".  The shell deals with it all for you.  You're expected to execute whole commands (e.g. `rm` to remove temporary files) in the action for a `trap` — and that's working at a very different level than catching signals in C code.  Granted, the shell is in C, but it detects that the signals arrive carefully and then executes the `trap` action outside the signal handler.

Answer (score 14):

> How to avoid using `printf` in a signal handler?

1. Always avoid it, will say: Just don't use `printf()` in signal handlers.
2. At least on POSIX conforming systems, you can use `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)` instead of `printf()`. Formatting may not be easy however: [Print int from signal handler using write or async-safe functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573000/print-int-from-signal-handler-using-write-or-async-safe-functions)

Comment: Alk `Always avoid it.` means? Avoid `printf()`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, as the OP was asking when to avoid using `printf()` in signal handlers.

Comment: Alk +1 for `2` point, check OP asking for **How** to avoid using `printf()` in signal handlers?

Answer (score 7):

For debugging purposes, I wrote a tool which verifies that you are in fact only calling functions on the `async-signal-safe` list, and prints a warning message for each unsafe function called within a signal context. While it doesn't solve the problem of wanting to call non async-safe functions from a signal context, it at least helps you find cases where you have done so accidentally.

The source code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/dwks/asyncsafe). It works by overloading `signal/sigaction`, then temporarily hijacking the `PLT` entries of unsafe functions; this causes calls to unsafe functions to be redirected to a wrapper.

Comment: GCC feature request: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-03/msg00210.html

Answer (score 3):

**Implement your own async-signal-safe `snprintf("%d` and use `write`**

It is not as bad as I thought, [How to convert an int to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c) has several implementations.

Since there are only two interesting types of data that signal handlers can access:

- `sig_atomic_t` globals
- `int` signal argument

this basically covers all interesting use cases.

The fact that `strcpy` is also signal safe makes things even better.

The POSIX program below prints to stdout the number of times it received SIGINT so far, which you can trigger with `Ctrl + C`, and the and signal ID.

You can exit the program with `Ctrl + \` (SIGQUIT).

main.c:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Calculate the minimal buffer size for a given type.
 *
 * Here we overestimate and reserve 8 chars per byte.
 *
 * With this size we could even print a binary string.
 *
 * - +1 for NULL terminator
 * - +1 for '-' sign
 *
 * A tight limit for base 10 can be found at:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c/32871108#32871108
 *
 * TODO: get tight limits for all bases, possibly by looking into
 * glibc's atoi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux/52127877#52127877
 */
#define ITOA_SAFE_STRLEN(type) sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT + 2

/* async-signal-safe implementation of integer to string conversion.
 *
 * Null terminates the output string.
 *
 * The input buffer size must be large enough to contain the output,
 * the caller must calculate it properly.
 *
 * @param[out] value  Input integer value to convert.
 * @param[out] result Buffer to output to.
 * @param[in]  base   Base to convert to.
 * @return     Pointer to the end of the written string.
 */
char *itoa_safe(intmax_t value, char *result, int base) {
    intmax_t tmp_value;
    char *ptr, *ptr2, tmp_char;
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ptr = result;
    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while (value);
    if (tmp_value < 0)
        *ptr++ = '-';
    ptr2 = result;
    result = ptr;
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while (ptr2 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr--= *ptr2;
        *ptr2++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return result;
}

volatile sig_atomic_t global = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char key_str[] = "count, sigid: ";
    /* This is exact:
     * - the null after the first int will contain the space
     * - the null after the second int will contain the newline
     */
    char buf[2 * ITOA_SAFE_STRLEN(sig_atomic_t) + sizeof(key_str)];
    enum { base = 10 };
    char *end;
    end = buf;
    strcpy(end, key_str);
    end += sizeof(key_str);
    end = itoa_safe(global, end, base);
    *end++ = ' ';
    end = itoa_safe(sig, end, base);
    *end++ = '\n';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, end - buf);
    global += 1;
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Unit test itoa_safe. */
    {
        typedef struct {
            intmax_t n;
            int base;
            char out[1024];
        } InOut;
        char result[1024];
        size_t i;
        InOut io;
        InOut ios[] = {
            /* Base 10. */
            {0, 10, "0"},
            {1, 10, "1"},
            {9, 10, "9"},
            {10, 10, "10"},
            {100, 10, "100"},
            {-1, 10, "-1"},
            {-9, 10, "-9"},
            {-10, 10, "-10"},
            {-100, 10, "-100"},

            /* Base 2. */
            {0, 2, "0"},
            {1, 2, "1"},
            {10, 2, "1010"},
            {100, 2, "1100100"},
            {-1, 2, "-1"},
            {-100, 2, "-1100100"},

            /* Base 35. */
            {0, 35, "0"},
            {1, 35, "1"},
            {34, 35, "Y"},
            {35, 35, "10"},
            {100, 35, "2U"},
            {-1, 35, "-1"},
            {-34, 35, "-Y"},
            {-35, 35, "-10"},
            {-100, 35, "-2U"},
        };
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ios)/sizeof(ios[0]); ++i) {
            io = ios[i];
            itoa_safe(io.n, result, io.base);
            if (strcmp(result, io.out)) {
                printf("%ju %d %s\n", io.n, io.base, io.out);
                assert(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Handle the signals. */
    if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "1")) {
        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
        while(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c
./main 1
```

After pressing Ctrl + C fifteen times, the terminal shows:

```
^Ccount, sigid: 0 2
^Ccount, sigid: 1 2
^Ccount, sigid: 2 2
^Ccount, sigid: 3 2
^Ccount, sigid: 4 2
^Ccount, sigid: 5 2
^Ccount, sigid: 6 2
^Ccount, sigid: 7 2
^Ccount, sigid: 8 2
^Ccount, sigid: 9 2
^Ccount, sigid: 10 2
^Ccount, sigid: 11 2
^Ccount, sigid: 12 2
^Ccount, sigid: 13 2
^Ccount, sigid: 14 2
```

where `2` is the signal number for `SIGINT`.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/6b4896846dfdca69e8d3f38fd3ede14c517438ef/posix/signal_write_safe.c).

Answer (score 2):

One technique which is especially useful in programs which have a *select loop* is to write a single byte down a pipe on receipt of a signal and then handle the signal in the select loop.  Something along these lines *(error handling and other details omitted for brevity)*:

```
static int sigPipe[2];

static void gotSig ( int num ) { write(sigPipe[1], "!", 1); }

int main ( void ) {
    pipe(sigPipe);
    /* use sigaction to point signal(s) at gotSig() */

    FD_SET(sigPipe[0], &readFDs);

    for (;;) {
        n = select(nFDs, &readFDs, ...);
        if (FD_ISSET(sigPipe[0], &readFDs)) {
            read(sigPipe[0], ch, 1);
            /* do something about the signal here */
        }
        /* ... the rest of your select loop */
    }
}
```

If you care *which* signal it was, then the byte down the pipe can be the signal number.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `write()` directly which is an async-signal-safe function.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
 
int main(void) { 
    write(1,"Hello World!", 12); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use printf in signal handlers if you are using the pthread library. unix/posix specifies that printf is atomic for threads cf Dave Butenhof reply here :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.programming.threads/1-bU71nYgqw
Note that in order to get a clearer picture of printf output,
**you should run your application in a console** (on linux use ctl+alt+f1 to start console 1),
rather than a pseudo-tty created by the GUI.

Comment: Signal handlers do not run in some separate thread, they run in the context of the thread that was running when the signal interrupt occurred. This answer is completely wrong.